# Is there any limitations of WCF synchronous call to Tcp/ip

Tags: multithreading, wcf, tcp

My WCF Service (concurrency-multiple) will receive a request and then contact another TCP/IP service synchronously to provide a response to client.

I have confused, is that ok to contact tcp/ip synchronously, I don't want block channel to serve only one request at a time. 
Am I correct in assuming that since service support multiple calls, synchronous call to tcp/ip doesn't affect.
Please comment if any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your WCF service will continue to accept requests and will create a thread for each request to external service.

Comment: Thanks, that will help, to go ahead in writing a RequestReply API for TCP/IP communication.